# rsync - How to make it delete directories or files recently added to the exclusions list

Tags: ubuntu, rsync

I use my NAS to back up several smaller systems - 8 of them.

As I have learned more and tuned my exclusions I see a whole lot of leftovers that I forgot to exclude earlier.

Say I decide to exclude all of /var/log for the backups.  kern* and messages* in particular can take up many GB of space each, and the contents are totally meaningless in a backup.

**Simply adding them to the --exclude list, even with --delete doesn't delete them because exclude makes the rsync program skip them entirely.**

**It does not operate the same way Robocopy /MIR does.**

Is there an answer to this bug?

---

Ideally, I would like rsync to do it automatically, but perhaps every time I add a new exclude I should just manually clean up old copies instead?

This worked to delete the leftovers:

```
cd /mnt/full
sudo rm -rf `sudo find -type d -name '.Trash-1000'`
```

as per the answer to

[Ubuntu 16.04 rsync - doing backups of the NAS server, can I tell it to exclude all the .Trash directories?](https://superuser.com/questions/1242451/ubuntu-16-04-rsync-doing-backups-of-the-nas-server-can-i-tell-it-to-exclude-a)

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------

ADDENDUM:  Xenoid gave the required answer by pointing out that there is a `--delete-excluded` switch.  I missed that.  It is exactly what I have been looking for so this will be automatic from now on.  TNX.

Here is a Q&A that talked directly to it, but which never came up in my Goggle Fu:

[What exactly will --delete-excluded do for rsync?](https://serverfault.com/questions/279609/what-exactly-will-delete-excluded-do-for-rsync)

Comment: How about the `--delete-before` and/or `--delete-after` options... play and test with those a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man rsync` says there is a `--delete-excluded` option: *also delete excluded files on the receiving side*.

Comment: Excellent info.  I didn't see that before.  That is precisely what I need.  Thank you, @Xenoid.  I see it here, too:  https://serverfault.com/questions/279609/what-exactly-will-delete-excluded-do-for-rsync